# strcat() causes segmentation fault only after program is finished?

Tags: c

Here's a program that summarizes text.  Up to this point, I'm counting the number of occurrences of each word in the text. But, I'm getting a segmentation fault in strcat.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x75985629 in strcat () from C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll
```

However, while stepping through the code, the program runs the `strcat()` function as expected. I don't receive the error until line 75, when the program ends.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXTEXT 1000
#define MAXLINE 200
#define MAXWORDS 200
#define MAXWORD 32

char *strtolower(char *d, const char *s, size_t len);

/* summarizer: summarizes text */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /* argument check */
    char *prog = argv[0];
    if (argc < 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: missing arguments, expected 1", prog);
        exit(1);
    }
    /* attempt to open file */
    FILE *fp;
    if (!(fp = fopen(argv[1], "r"))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Couldn't open file %s", prog, argv[1]);
        exit(2);
    }
    /* read file line by line */
    char line[MAXLINE], text[MAXTEXT];
    while ((fgets(line, MAXTEXT, fp))) {
        strncat(text, line, MAXLINE); 
    }
    /* separate into words and count occurrences */
    struct wordcount {
        char *word;
        int count;
    };
    struct wordcount words[MAXWORDS];
    char *token, *delim = " \t\n.,!?";
    char word[MAXWORD], textcpy[strlen(text)+1]; /*len of text and \0 */
    int i, j, is_unique_word = 1;
    strcpy(textcpy, text);
    token = strtok(textcpy, delim);
    for (i = 0; i < MAXWORDS && token; i++) {
        strtolower(word, token, strlen(token));
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        /* check if word exists */
        for (j = 0; words[j].word && j < MAXWORDS; j++) {
            if (!strcmp(word, words[j].word)) {
                is_unique_word = 0;
                words[j].count++;
            }
        }
        /* add to word list of unique */
        if (is_unique_word) {
            strcpy(words[i].word, word);
            words[i].count++;
        }
        is_unique_word = 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

/* strtolower: copy str s to dest d, returns pointer of d */
char *strtolower(char *d, const char *s, size_t len) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        d[i] = tolower(*(s+i));
    }

    return d;
}
```

Comment: 1) `text[MAXTEXT]` --> `text[MAXTEXT] = ""`

Comment: and `strncat` **appends** up to `n` characters, so this code will happily write out of the bounds of `text`, starting from the second iteration.

Comment: What @BLUEPIXY means, is that `strcat()` expects it's parameters to be `'\0'` terminated, a concept that if understood one would not use `strcat()`.

Comment: You use `strncat(text, line, MAXLINE);` when `text` hasn't been initialized.

Comment: @DavidTran The `strcat` function requires an existing, valid string to concatenate onto. Otherwise, use `strcpy`. When you first pass `text` to `strncat`, it contains garbage, not a string.

Comment: 2) `words[j].word` using uninitialized variable.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but reading the file line by line just to append all lines into a single buffer is overly complicated and inefficient. You should get the file size, allocate a buffer accordingly and read the whole file with a single `fread`.

Comment: There are too many bugs for a concise answer. `MAXTEXT` and `MAXLINE` are mixed up, `strncpy()` is not correctly understood (must be e.g. `strncat(text, line, MAXLINE - strlen(text))`), etc.

Comment: What prevents `strlen(token)` from exceeded `MAXWORD`?

Comment: You should consider to rewrite your program from scratch splitting it into functions.

Comment: Note that `strncat()` is the more dangerous version of `strcat()` — it has a different interface from any other `str*()` function.  If you can use `strncat()` safely, you have enough information that you don't need to use it, and therefore shouldn't use it — ever.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler don't you mean `strncpy()` here?

Comment: `strcpy(words[i].word, word);` the `word` field is a pointer that is never initialized. Definitely too many bugs here.

Comment: OK. I'll rewrite and try again.

Comment: The `strtolower`  is wrong: you forgot to set the NUL strin g terminator at the end of the destination string.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: I'm referring to `strncat()`—`strncpy()` has its own set of problems, but at least the length given is the length of the target buffer, not some other number altogether—the number of characters that can be added apart from the null, as with `strncat()`. Note that even `char buffer[32] = ""; strncat(buffer, "string that is more than thirty-two characters", sizeof(buffer));` triggers a buffer overflow. At least using `strncpy()` wouldn't overflow the buffer—it wouldn't null-terminate the result (it wouldn't be a string, therefore)—but … No; `strncat()` is more lethal than safe.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler well, of course this has its problems, I was just confused by you stating it "*has a different interface from any other `str*()` function*" which is IMHO especially true for `strncpy()`. The added 0 terminator in `strncat()` is a similar issue like `char x[5]; scanf("%5s", x);` :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Aside from the odd call, do you an OF issue with `char buffer[32] = ""; strncat(buffer, "string that is more than thirty-two characters", sizeof(buffer)-1);`  (-1 added)

Comment: @chux: with the empty buffer and `sizeof(buffer)-1`, `strncat()` works, but if the buffer's empty, you barely need to use it, and the `sizeof(buffer)-1` is oddball (an hence forgettable, so people forget that the `-1` is needed).  I dislike `strncat()` intensely, even more than `strncpy()`; neither is a stellar interface, but at least with `strncpy()`, if you specify `sizeof(buffer)` correctly, you don't get overflows. I don't use `strncat()`; I seldom use `strncpy()` either, because I need to know whether strings will be truncated so I need to know how long they are, so I've got all the info.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: `scanf()` also has a disconnect between the general usage (where `sizeof(x)` is the size to specify); another problem.  There's also the issue that you can't specify the length to use analogously to the `*` notation in `printf()` formats; you have to hard-code it in to the format string, or create the format string on the fly. There are warts in the standard C library, inherited from its legacy systems. If you were designing it from scratch, there are numerous things that you'd do differently. These are some of them. There are others (`%5c` in `scanf()` does not null terminate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the loop: `while ((fgets(line, MAXTEXT, fp))) strncat(text, line, MAXLINE);`. It is incorrect for multiple reasons:

- `text` is uninitialized, concatenating a string to it has undefined behavior. Undefined behavior may indeed cause a crash *after* the end of the function, for example if the return address was overwritten.
- there is no reason to use `strncat()` with a length of `MAXLINE`, the string read by `fgets()` has at most `MAXLINE-1` bytes.
- you do not check if there is enough space at the end of `text` to concatenate the contents of `line`.  `strncat(dest, src, n)` copies **at most** `n` bytes from `src` to the end of `dest` and always sets a null terminator. It is not a *safe* version of `strcat()`. If the line does not fit at the end of `text`, you have unexpected behavior, and again you can observe a crash *after* the end of the function, for example if the return address was overwritten.

You could just try and read the whole file with `fread`:

```
/* read the file into the text array */
char text[MAXTEXT];
size_t text_len = fread(text, 1, sizeof(text) - 1, fp);
text[text_len] = '\0';
```

If `text_len == sizeof(text) - 1`, the file is potentially too large for the `text` array and the `while` loop would have caused a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one problem because you create line with MAXLINE size (200), then you fgets() up to MAXTEXT (1000) chars into it.

Comment: This is normal behavior, when the behavior is undefined. Buffer overflows are NEVER checked.

Answer (score 1):

Destination string of `strncat` function shall be null terminated. You need to null terminate `text` before passing it to `strncat` function. You also have to write only upto `MAXLINE-1` bytes and leave a space for `'\0'` appended by `strncat` at the end to stop buffer overflow.

```
char line[MAXLINE], text[MAXTEXT] = {'\0'};  
while ((fgets(line, MAXTEXT, fp)))
{
    strncat(text, line, MAXLINE-1); 
}
```

Comment: For completeness: `text[MAXTEXT] = "";` would do as well.

Comment: @alk; Or even `text[MAXTEXT] = {0};`